# MIT Integration Bee 2017 problem:$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac 1 {1+\tan^{2017} x} \, dx$ : Need hints

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, contest-math

[This is a problem from MIT integration bee 2017.](http://www.mit.edu/%7Esame/pdf/qualifying_round_2017_answers.pdf)

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac 1 {1+\tan^{2017} x} \, dx$$

I have tried substitution method, multiplying numerator and denominator with $\sec^2x$, breaking the numerator in terms of linear combination of the denominator and the derivative of it. None of these methods work.

Some hints please?

Comment: what is MIT integration bee 2017?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner http://www.mit.edu/~same/pdf/qualifying_round_2017_answers.pdf

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Every year, MIT has a competition for undergraduates where they compete to see who can integrate difficult expressions fastest.It's like a spelling bee, but for integrals.

Comment: thank you very much, usefull problems

Comment: The **original** problem is a definite one which is very easily evaluated.

Comment: Perhaps this way of using the word "bee" is not well known outside North America. If it were, I'd say the term "MIT integration bee" is self-explanatory.

Comment: Regardless of power it is $\pi/4$ for the case from $0$ to $\pi/2$

Comment: for indefinite case you will have a quite large mess of log(), sin() and cos(), humanly intractable, but doable I suppose

Comment: @guyfsone The original question, as posed by the OP, was with an indefinite integral. Is it valid editing for others to change the question so drastically? I understand why it was done of course... but?  My comment/question is to be taken at face value - I do not mean to criticize! Comments?

Comment: Yes but which is not what is written in the provided link. check his own link. and you see

Comment: @GuyFsone As I said, I quite understand. On the other hand, I think - I know I just said I wasn't criticizing, and now it sounds like I am - sorry!!! - that maybe in this case it would have been better to point it out, and ask the OP to update the question as desired. (I hope I'm not sounding like a jerk.)

Answer (score 10):

Try using $$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \, dx$$

and the fact that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-x) = \cot(x)$ to convert to get the following:
$$I = \int_0^{\pi / 2} \frac 1 {1+ \tan^{2017}(x)} \, dx = 
 \int_0^{\pi / 2} \frac 1 {1+ \tan^{2017}(\pi/2-x)} \, dx \\
 =  \int_0^{\pi / 2} \frac 1 {1+ \cot^{2017}(x)} \, dx =  \int_0^{\pi / 2} \frac{\tan^{2017}(x)}{1+ \tan^{2017}(x)} \, dx$$

Hence

$$2I = \int_{0}^{\pi / 2}  dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: The sad thing is it wouldn't have work if the upper limit of integration would be $\pi /4$.

Comment: @Mockingbird Did you suppose the question to be indefinite or definite?

Comment: Will the problem use different strategy if the upper limit would have been $\frac{\pi}{4}$ ?

Comment: @BAYMAX That's my question also!

Comment: Obviously this method will not work there! This *reflective* property only works under special circumstances. It would be interesting to see a closed solution to that, you can put that as a question.

Answer (score 7):

Setting the change of variable: $u=\frac\pi2-x $ and since, $\tan x =\cot(\frac\pi2 -x)$ we have, 
\begin{align}
& \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{2017} x} \, dx = \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{2017} (\frac\pi2-u) } \, du \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{1}{1+\cot^{2017}u} \, du = \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\tan^{2017} u}{1+\tan^{2017} u} \, du \color{red}{= \frac{\pi}{2} -\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{2017} u} \, du}
\end{align}

That is $$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{2017} x} \, dx =\frac\pi4$$

Comment: Do you have a strong preference for $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac \pi 2}$ rather than $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Sir which one is appropriate because I prefer the first one

Comment: In a "displayed" context I prefer $\dfrac \pi 2,$ but when the fraction is in a superscript then I'm more comfortable with the second one.